# Play a sound for a certain duration

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I have a mp3 file and I would like to play it from one position  and for a certain duration.
I have first used  the Sound class, the play method where I can specify the start but not the duration.

I have looked then at SoundEffect class where you can specify a duration and a startTime.
However I do not know how to play it from a AS3 class not from MXML : there is a play method ... but I get no sound !! Help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to implement the duration logic yourself using a [Timer](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/Timer.html) object and then calling Stop on your Sound when the time elapses.

Comment: Yes. I thought doing it like this but this may be not so occurate. Actually I want to split the mp3 file into n (short) chuncks (2s) and being able to play one of those at wish.

I will try it. Thanks

Comment: I just implemented it and this is not occurate at all. However I can put some silence in between sound chuncks for managing it, I guess. If someone has a solution with SoundEffect class or oher means ... Thanks

Comment: Sorry it didn't work.  I'd like to know the answer to this as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using KitchenSync (http://kitchensynclib.googlecode.com) which provides control over sound files and code-based timing.

Check out the KSSoundController class